# Galeria de fotos por categoria (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, imagem

**Aqui estão os códigos:**

**VIEW:**

```
<div class="container">
                <?php
                    echo form_open_multipart('admin/exibe_fotos/index');
                ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="categoria">Selecione a categoria desejada:</label>
                        <select name="categorias" class="form-control">
                            <?php foreach ($listarCategorias->result() as $row) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $row->idCategoria; ?>"><?php echo $row->dscCategoria; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg float-right" value="Buscar fotos">
                <?php 
                    echo form_close(); 
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="container-galeria">
                <?php foreach ($mostrarFotos->result() as $row) : ?>
                <div class="card row mx-3 my-3" style="width: 18rem; display:inline-block">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/upload/'.$row->caminhoImagem); ?>" alt="<?php echo $row->tituloImagem; ?>">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $row->tituloImagem; ?></h5>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Marcar</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
public function __construct()
{ 
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url')); 
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('layout/admin/sidebar');

    $this->load->model('admin/tbdimagem');
    $dados["mostrarFotos"] = $this->tbdimagem->listarImagensCategoria();
    $this->load->view('admin/marcacao_fotos', $dados);

    $this->load->view('layout/admin/footer');
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
function listarImagensCategoria()
{
    $idCategoria = $this->input->post('categorias');

    $subselect = "SELECT idImagem FROM imagem_categoria WHERE idCategoria = '$idCategoria'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbdimagem');
    $this->db->where("idImagem", "$subselect");

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

**Quando seleciono uma categoria e clico no botão para trazer as fotos, simplesmente sou redirecionado para essa tela:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Primeiro você não deveria utilizar variaveis post no model, model é parte de banco

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo utilizando meu código mesmo, de como ficaria sem passar a variável post no model? Ajudaria muito... Todo lugar que procuro está desta maneira...

Comment: O melhor seria passar a variavel no metodo (do model) pelo controller

Comment: Por exemplo, no controller ficaria assim: $idCategoria = $this->input->post('categorias'); e na chamada para o model, eu passaria dessa forma: $this->load->model('admin/tbdimagem', $idCategoria);
Assim, na minha função do model, eu colocaria desse jeito: function listarImagensCategoria($idCategoria){}

Comment: Aqui não $this->load->model('admin/tbdimagem', $idCategoria); aqui sim $this->tbdimagem->listarImagensCategoria();, o load do model é só o load